# Why won't ajax let me print the php echo values?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm new to ajax and i'm having some trouble trying to print the echo values from my php upload page. My goal is to get that echo, which is the result, and print that within my span div.

Here's my JavaScript.

```
     $(document).ready(function (e) {
        $('#myForm').on('submit',(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var formData = new FormData(this); 
             $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url: $(this).attr('action'),
                data:formData,
                cache:false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                success:function(data){
                    console.log("success");
                    console.log(data);
                    $("#myForm")[0].reset();
                    $("#result").append(data);
                },
                error: function(data){
                    console.log("error");
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });

        }));

    });
```

Here's my HTML

```
<form action="postphoto" id="myForm" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                      <input type="file" onchange="readURL(this);" name="profilepic" id="ImageBrowse"/>
                      <br>
                      <img id="blah" src="#" alt="" height="300" width="400" />
                      <br>
                      <br>
                      <textarea class="form-control" name="description" rows="1" cols="40" placeholder="Description"></textarea>  
                      <br>
                      <textarea class="form-control" name="tagone" rows="1" cols="10" placeholder="Tag"></textarea>  
                      <textarea class="form-control" name="tagtwo" rows="1" cols="10" placeholder="Tag"></textarea>  
                      <textarea class="form-control" name="tagthree" rows="1" cols="10" placeholder="Tag"></textarea>  
                      <br>
                      <textarea class="form-control" name="content" rows="5" cols="40" placeholder="Inspiration behind this.."></textarea> <br>
                      <textarea class="form-control" name="url" rows="1" cols="10" placeholder="Url"></textarea> 
                      <em>Separate words in the url by a dash. For example, fashion-fashion.</em><br>
                      <span id="result"></span>
                      <br><input type="submit" class="form-control" id="sub" name="uploadpic" value="Upload">
                      </form>
```

Here's the php

```
       $chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
       $rand_dir_name = substr(str_shuffle($chars), 0, 15);
       $rand_dir_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conx,$rand_dir_name);

       mkdir("userdata/user_photos/$rand_dir_name");

       if (file_exists("userdata/user_photos/$rand_dir_name/".@$_FILES["profilepic"]["name"]))
       {
        echo @$_FILES["profilepic"]["name"]." Already exists";
       }
       else
       {
         $query = "SELECT * FROM photos WHERE link='$url'";
         $query = $db_conx->query($query);
         $checks = mysqli_num_rows($query);

         if ($checks == 0) {

            move_uploaded_file(@$_FILES["profilepic"]["tmp_name"],"userdata/user_photos/$rand_dir_name/".$_FILES["profilepic"]["name"]);
            //echo "Uploaded and stored in: userdata/profile_pics/$rand_dir_name/".@$_FILES["profilepic"]["name"];
            $profile_pic_name = @$_FILES["profilepic"]["name"];
            $profile_pic_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conx,$profile_pic_name);
            $img_id_before_md5 = "$rand_dir_name/$profile_pic_name";
            $img_id = md5($img_id_before_md5);
            $profile_pic_query = "INSERT INTO photos VALUES ('','test','$user','$date','$description','http://website.com/userdata/user_photos/$rand_dir_name/$profile_pic_name','no','$url','$tag1','$tag2','$tag3','$content')";
            $profile_pic_query1 = $db_conx->query($profile_pic_query);
            echo "Your photo was uploaded!";
         }
         else
         {
          echo "Link has already been taken.";
         }
       }
    }
    }
    ?>
```

The question still remains though. Why doesn't my ajax print the echo's within my result span. If you could help me out it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Does the response of the request have the values?

Comment: I dont think so, maybe thats why it wont print out

Comment: Does the console print your requested `msg`?

Comment: Check which conditions are being executed.